# How do I set the HttpConfiguration on an HttpRequestMessage for testing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api

My controller makes use of `CreateResponse` on the request object. So in order to test my controller I need to set an instance of `HttpConfiguration` on the `HttpRequestMessage` because the `CreateResponse` expects this configuration to be there.

Nowadays, to aid with testing, there are setters for all sorts of properties but on `HttpRequestMessage` there is only a `GetConfiguration` method and no apparent setter.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
...

ThingController controller = new ThingController(... dependencies ...);

// Fake the configuration.
//
var httpConfig = new HttpConfiguration();
controller.Configuration = httpConfig;

// Fake the request.
//
var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, "http://mstest/things/1");
httpRequest.Properties[HttpPropertyKeys.HttpConfigurationKey] = httpConfig;

controller.Request = httpRequest;
```

Note the line 2nd from bottom. Sneaky.

Comment: that this static class, HttpPropertyKeys, is not better documented is beyond me